# Late withdrawal from all the courses after the census date as I had an accident and will be undergoing surgery

Tags: graduate-admissions, health, administration

I will be undergoing surgery due to an accident that happened to me 2 months before the start of the term and I have been. The term has nearly ended and I wont be able to sit for final exams as I will be undergoing surgery based on doctors advice.On top of that this injury has been affecting my studies to a great extent.But if I withdraw from courses right now, I will be excluded from the university.I need help regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to see the people at the university - we cannot give you a definitive answer as regulations etc vary by location etc

There are most likely student advisors or equivalent, admissions dept, your course head, even the department dean who can all be contacted about your situation.

Make sure you have documentary evidence so they have something to work with - doctor’s letters etc

Best of luck.

Comment: I faced a similar situation, when diagnosed with cancer requiring surgery while I was a graduate student. The graduate student advisor knew the right petition to present to the right committee to let me drop from full time to just a couple of course units of research.

Comment: My experience, both as a student and as a faculty member, has been that universities are very accommodating of medical problems.  As this answer says, make sure you have documentation showing that you truly have a medical need; I'd expect the appropriate authorities can and will solve the problem for you.