# Discontinuing Masters Program in Coursework after census date

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, computer-science, withdraw

I am planning to discontinue my studies due to health and financial reasons.Will I be able to get a job after this? I have good programming skills though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Late withdrawal from all the courses after the census date as I had an accident and will be undergoing surgery](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/130417/late-withdrawal-from-all-the-courses-after-the-census-date-as-i-had-an-accident)

Comment: Your first question on the same topic was put on hold. Instead of asking the same thing in a new question with fewer details, if you think the first question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please [edit that question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/130417/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you can get a job or not depends on the market and on your skills. It also depends on how you market yourself and can exploit your experience in relevant things.

I don't understand the concept of "census date" but assume it is a date after which you can't drop without (possibly poor) grades. But your earlier question here implies that you might be able to make a case for an exception to normal rules due to an accident and a situation outside your control. I hope you are pursuing that avenue.

In many places programmers are in high demand, so *some* job is probably open to you. How attractive it is depends on all those other factors. You will need to assure a potential employer that the accident and its aftermath doesn't affect your suitability for a job, perhaps.